# Using HDF5 with different data types

Tags: c#, hdf5

What is the correct way to read data from .h5 file?

There are different types of data which are stored in the table. The data type is "Compound"
due to the structure of this file.

To open the needed table I use:

```
struct metadata
{
    public Chararray a;
    public int b;
    public float c;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct Chararray
{
    private char* recordedText;
    public char* RecordedText
    {
        get
        {
            return recordedText;
        }
        set
        {
            recordedText = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string s;

        IntPtr ipp = (IntPtr)this.recordedText;
        s =System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ipp);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipp);

        return s;
    }
}
```

To read the data

```
H5DataSetId dsetId = H5D.open(fileID, "/metadata/songs");
```

where fileID is H5FileId.

```
metadata[] s1 = new metadata[1];
H5DataTypeId dt = H5D.getType(dsetId);
H5D.read(dsetId, dt, new H5Array<metadata>(s1));
```

However, the output in `s1` is not correct.